# Removing characters from the beginning of several files

Tags: batch-file

I basically have lots of files, generally in either .xls or .pdf format and I need to remove the first 8 characters from every file. the standard format is something like:

abc 123 restoffilenameiwanttokeep.pdf

I want to get rid of 'abc 123 ' and I have some code that seems to work for some file but not others, see below -

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
LFNFOR On

for %%a in (*.pdf) do (
set oldName=%%a
set newName=!oldName:~8!
Ren "%%a" "!newName!"
)
endlocal
```

for some files it works, for others it has removed up to 10 chars and I'm not sure why, is it due to the last char being a space? but if so why does it work with some and not others? its very perplexing.

I'm on Win XP and using a batch file to do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Adam

Comment: Can you provide examples of filenames that failed (i.e. that removed more than 8 characters).

Comment: The first character of a file can't be a space (also the last). This `set newName=!oldName:~8!` removes eight chars ....

Comment: they all begin with the same layout abc 123 restoffilename. am i correct in thinking that 8 chars is enough? (3 letters, 3 numbers and 2 spaces) one that removed more than 8 basically did 10, and cut the word in half

Comment: What was the name of "one"?

Comment: ok, sorry, one that worked was "CWB 872 Air handling unit 12M.pdf" but then "CWB 932 Supply Air grilles and Diffusers 12M.pdf" gets cut to "grilles and Diffusers 12M.pdf"

Comment: No, your code worked here. Btw: `LFNFOR` is _not_ a Windows command.

Comment: hmmm weird (cheers, i'd copied and pasted it from a previous example lol) would be a problem if the folder had 164 files in it, its probably the work computer being a pain

Comment: Bet it isn't final :) I believe that the strange behaviour you're observing may be the new name being re-processed. Hence, a dir/b would seem to be in order...

Comment: ahh I wondered if that might of been an issue, how would a dir/b be implemented in the code? as I'm a little unsure of the syntax, cheers

Comment: The `for %%a` loop instantly reads the file name and gives it to the `do`  part. The `for /f` loop first reads all file names and gives it subsequently one by one to the `do` part. But sometimes this also failed by unknown reasons. In that cases you must use the following code: `for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b ^|sort /r') do ...`. OK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Peter Wright spotted the problem. You need to change your `for` loop to something like this:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b *.pdf') do (
...
)
```

The `/f` option combined with the single quotes around the `dir` command, tells the `for` loop that it needs to execute that `dir` and loop over the results.

The `"delims="` after the `/f` prevents it from matching any delimiters between words, otherwise the `%%a` would only return the first space separated word.

And the `/b` option on the `dir` command, just gives you a bare version of the directory listing with nothing but the names, since that is obviously all you're interested in.

Comment: I think we may have a winner there, that seems to work ok, big thank you folks, this has definitely made my 12 hour shift more interesting than normal haha, love a good problem solve (I had spent ages looking before I posted here)

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion for slightly better code (supports `!` and `^`):

```
@echo off &setlocal

for %%a in (*.pdf) do (
set "oldName=%%a"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "newName=!oldName:~8!"
Ren "!oldname!" "!newName!"
endlocal
)
endlocal
```

Comment: As I see, tis also doesn't support `!` or `^`  in file names :(.

Comment: Arrgh, but now it does ! :)

Comment: @Endoro: Due to the for-in-do bug which reprocesses files when they change name, use the long form of for /f to gather the filenames.